# EmberJS tests that require data files

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, qunit

I am writing a test in Ember-cli to test that my class can read xlsx files. However, I don't know how to tell Ember/qUnit to export the test file to the dist folder with the tests so my tests can find it when running in the browser. This is what my test looks like. But it cannot find "url" when executed because it hasn't copied the file to the dist folder. How do I tell Ember to copy the test file?

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import Ember from 'ember';
import XlsxParser from '../../../objects/sheetParsers/XlsxParser';

module('Unit | XLSX Parser');

test('it works', function(assert) {
  var sheetParser = XlsxParser.create();
  var done1 = assert.async();
  var url = "/testFiles/excelTest.xlsx";

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("GET", url, true);
  oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  oReq.onload = function(e) {
    var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

    /* convert data to binary string */
    var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
    var arr = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
    var binaryData = arr.join("");

    /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
    sheetParser.parseSheet(binaryData);
  }

  oReq.send();

  assert.ok("done");
  done1();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I placed the files under public/tests/testFiles in the ember-cli project and it merged it with the "tests" directory that was already in the dist folder. I also changed my url to tests/testFiles/exceltest.xls

I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sensible way to solve the problem. One problem I see is that you introduce a testing file into production assets. You can import testing asset's conditionally. First, create `vendor/fixtures` in your project's directory. Then add the following to your project's `ember-cli-build.js`:

```js
const environment = EmberApp.env();
const isTest = environment === 'test';
if (isTest) {
    app.import('vendor/fixtures/my-test-file.csv', { type: 'test' });
}
```

This, however, works quite well and will only copy assets to `dist/fixtures/` when `ember build` is invoked with the test flag (`--environment test`), or when you run `ember test`. I had tried creating the `fixtures` folder in my application's `tests/` directory but could not get it importing.